# really weird symbol in php?

Tags: php

what does the ∫ symbol mean in php?  Here is copy/paste of my var dump.. note the @user_id symbol then(0). Thanks!  ``

```
           object(dbStoredProcedure)#13 (9) {
  ["dbh:private"]=>
  resource(27) of type (mssql link)
  ["sp_name:private"]=>
  string(24) "[dbo].[user_account_ins]"
  ["sp_parameters:private"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["stmt:private"]=>
  resource(50) of type (mssql statement)
  ["parameters"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["@error"]=>
    &string(0) ""
    ["@user_id"]=>
    ∫(0)
  }
  ["results"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["result"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["query"]=>
  NULL
  ["error"]=>
  bool(false)
}
```

Comment: Someone named an object as '∫'?

Comment: ... interesting find. The indefinite integral of zero is a constant...

Comment: @Franz: Integral(5) = 5x + C, where C is an arbitrary constant. Integral(0) = 0x + C = C, so its just a constant, not necessarily the same as f(x) = 0.

Comment: Right, because a derivative of a constant is 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your browser just displays the HTML entity reference `&int` as `∫`.

Comment: hmmmm yeah is looking like that might be it

Comment: @luis: Didn’t you take a look at the plain output of PHP?